# connect to postgresql within private network from cloud machine

Tags: postgresql

There is a postgresql instance in a private network with internet access (DB pc). It can NOT be accessed from outside and won't be. I need to connect to this postgresql instance from an app on the cloud (APP pc). I can write and run any application on DB in order to open postgresql instance into the other side.

Now I'm making a simple TCP connection between DB machine and APP machine (DB to APP) and sending request command from APP and get response from DB after querying postgresql locally. This bothers me! I feel like I can't rely on this connection. If I could make direct connection to DB postgresql in APP it will be more stable.

Is there any way to direct connection to the private postgresql instance from cloud environment? (I can not open postgresql to the outside of network)
Any kind of code piece in any language would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really about programming but rather network configuration.  You may have better answers on https://serverfault.com/.  But, generally, common choices would be a VPN between your cloud machine and on-prem machine or IP based security where only the IP of the cloud machine can connect.  There may be others.

Comment: thanks for quick reply @stdunbar. I tried to mention in question this is not a case. It never be accessible from outside of network. I need to write my own vpn-like service and make first contact to cloud and then cloud app could be access postgresql.

Comment: Are you saying that the app and the db hosts are in the same (virtual, private, cloud) network?

Comment: @Bergi no, think of that the DB is my local pc and APP is in any cloud based server (DO, AZURE, etc.)

Comment: @JamesDeSouza then stdunbar is spot on, you want to connect both your local pc and the cloud host to a vpn. That's exactly what they were made for. It's not clear why you say "*I need to write my own vpn-like service*" - you don't need to write that yourself, and you probably shouldn't.

Comment: The easiest option would even be an ssh tunnel to forward the port from your local host to the remote cloud host. You can open the connection from your local pc, it does not need to be accessed from the outside.

Comment: A VPN is not a connection from the outside world per se.  In this case it would be a connection between two and only two machines.  You would allow the VPN through your firewall on the on-prem side but nothing else would or could connect.  Rolling your own code for this is likely a bad idea - use something that has been battle tested for years.

Comment: You are describing 'reverse tunnelling', such as implemented in 'ssh' using '-R' flag.  This is not really a programming question, nor is it specifically about PostgreSQL.